# How do I create a new Profile Object in C# for the SalesForce API

Tags: c#, api, salesforce

I am attempting to create a new SalesForce Profile object through their API.  The doc shows that the Profile object does have a create() method, but when I attempt to create a new Profile object I receive an error stating, “entity type cannot be inserted: Profile”.  I have run a describeSObjects(new string[]{"Profile"}); and I have found the DescribeSObjectResult has a creatable = False.  Is there a way to use the API to create new Profile objects or am I stuck using the SalesForce.com Administration Setup UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create new profiles via the enterprise/partner APIs, just update existing ones, but i believe you can create new profiles via the [metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm).